# How do I stop git from tracking a file that I now have in my .gitignore but not have it removed from other machines when pulled?

Tags: git

I have accidentally been tracking two `.db` files in my repo. I added `*.db` to my `.gitignore`. The files are still tracked though since I've added them and committed them before. I used `git rm --cached file_name.db` to stop tracking the files, but I understand that when I commit and push this and then pull from another machine, these files will be removed from that environment.

What can I do to stop tracking these files, have them in my `.gitignore`, and not have them removed from other environments when I pull?

Comment: I don't think you can. A thought struck me that I don't know what would happen if you retroactively rewrote history to never include that file but I suspect it may mess it up anyway. But other than that, there is no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Or rather, *you* can't.  Each person who has a repository *can*, but *they* have to do it.

The problem is that "tracked-ness" is a property that exists *in those other clones*.  A file is *tracked* if it is in Git's index.  If it is not in the index, it is *untracked*.  That's it—it's that simple—but the problem is, every Git repository has *its own* index.<sup>1</sup>

That is, suppose you have some repository you're treating as the "gold master" or "source of truth" or whatever.  For simplicity, let's claim that this repository is also `--bare`, i.e., has no work-tree.<sup>2</sup>  This means we don't have to worry about whether there is a cop yof the `*.db` files (or whatever files): they *can't* exist as there is no work-tree.  We'll call this Gold Master / Source-of-Truth repository "SoT".

But each *clone* of SoT *does* have a work-tree, and therefore an index.  Clones A, B, and C each have *their own* index and work-tree.  By mistake, commit `badf00d` stores `crucial.db` *in the commit*, and at this point, repositories A, B, and C have done a `git checkout badf00d` (or `git checkout master` where `master` names commit `badf00d`).

File `crucial.db` exists in the work-tree of repositories A, B, and C, and *is tracked* in the repositories A, B, and C.  Checking out commit `badf00d` required that Git:

- copy `crucial.db` from commit `badf00d` into the index, and
- copy this `crucial.db` from the index into the work-tree

(this is how `git checkout` works, after all) so now `crucial.db` is in the index on A, B, and C, so `crucial.db` is tracked in repositories A, B, and C.

You now—*anywhere*, in *any* repository, perhaps even one of A, B, or C—*remove* `crucial.db` from the index, without removing it from your work-tree.  You then make a *new commit*, `fedf00d`, that *doesn't* have `crucial.db` inside it.  You now deliver `fedf00d` to the SoT repository.

If you did this *on* A, B, or C, *that* repository is now safe: it's already *on* commit `fedf00d`, still has `crucial.db` in its work-tree, and `crucial.db` is *not* in its index right now, because that's where you manually removed it *from* the index in order to make commit `fedf00d`.

But in any repository—A, B, or C included, but *any* repository *anywhere* counts—where:

- the index is still based on `badf00d`, and
- the work-tree matches the index

then *in that repository*, after obtaining new commit `fedf00d`, *any* of these commands:

- `git checkout fedf00d`
- `git merge` that does a fast-forward to `fedf00d`, e.g., via `git pull`
- unconflicted `git merge` of `fedf00d` that *doesn't* do a fast-forward
- `git reset --hard fedf00d` (which is the effect of a fast-forward merge)

tells Git: *make my index and work-tree match that of `fedf00d`*.  The process of making the *index* match involves *removing* `crucial.db`, and to make the work-tree come along for the ride, Git **removes `crucial.db` from the work-tree**.

In other words, **it is the fact that this file is tracked, in this repository, that makes the work-tree copy vanish** when switching commits.  If you first carefully *remove* `crucial.db` from the index—so that it's not tracked—in this repository, *then* your switch to commit `fedf00d` won't *remove* `crucial.db` from the work-tree.

Any time you `git checkout badf00d`, though—in *any* repository—that puts `crucial.db` *back into the index*, so that it is now tracked again.  If you now switch *from* `badf00d` to `fedf00d`, Git will *remove* `crucial.db` from the work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>Logically, an index is associated with a work-tree.  So if you use `git worktree add` to add a second work-tree to some repository, that adds a second index as well.

<sup>2</sup>Without a work-tree, the index has no real function.  Because Git was not originally designed to have zero-to-N work-trees, though, a bare repository still *does* have an index, or a potential index.  This bare-repository-index gets used if you try to use Git as a deployment system as well as a version control system, sometimes with disastrous results, which is why I don't recommend using Git as a deployment system.

---

#### There are a couple of ways to view this

My favorite is to consider particular commits "radioactive" (at least mildly so):

- Checking out a "radioactive" commit pollutes something: your index, at the least, and maybe your work-tree as well.
- Switching away from this "radioactive" commit, Git will remove the radioactive files: the bad ones in your index, and—if they got into your work-tree, which they probably did—those too.
- So if you have one of these in your repository, use great care whenever you might visit it:

  - Wear protective clothing (move endangered files out of the work-tree)
- And, though "rewriting" history is quite painful, you might consider doing a rewrite to eliminate these radioactive commits from your repository, so that no one will stumble over them while doing source-code-archaeology.

There's a simpler way to deal with all of this though, which is: **Don't use Git as a deployment system.**  Always *deploy* software with something else, that doesn't leave a tempting Git repository in the location in which the system is deployed.  That way, `crucial.db` *is never under source control in the first place*.  The deployment area *is not a Git repository*.  It is literally impossible to add `crucial.db` *to* the repository, and therefore impossible to ever get it *into* any commit.

"But my databases need to be backed-up!"  Why, yes, they *do*.  But Git is not a *backup system*.  Version control and backup are different activities.  Do the backup with a backup system, not a version control system.  Do the deployment with a deployment system.  "One size fits all" is convenient, but fictional: don't fall into this trap.